# Connect Python to SAGE 100 MAS 90 4.0 ODBC Driver

Tags: python, etl

Is there a way to connect SAGE 100 through python with MAS 90 4.0 ODBC Driver (PVXODBC.DLL)? I have tried using pyodbc but have been getting an error. I have set up the DSN Name with the proper creds in windows. I am using the DSN to connect to the database through pentaho (an etl tool) and it works.

```
pyodbc.connect("DSN=DSN_NAME")

Error: ('IM014', '[IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN
contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application (0)
(SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I have also tried this:

```
pyodbc.connect("DSN=DSN_NAME;DRIVER={MAS 90 4.0 ODBC DRIVER}")
```

I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using a 32-bit driver with 64-bit ODBC, or vice versa.

Comment: It looks like changing to a 32-bit ODBC fix that issue but now I have this issue and haven't had much luck. 
    Error: ('S1C00', '[S1C00] [ProvideX][ODBC Driver]Driver not capable     (1010) (SQLSetConnnectAttr(SQL_ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT))')

Comment: Here's the most likely cause of that error. You'll find it often occurs in drivers which are written for applications or file systems, not databases. Add autocommit=True to your connection parameters. https://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/FAQs#Connecting_fails_with_an_error_about_SQL_ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT

Answer (score 0):

This bit of code works for me:

```
import pyodbc
serial = '100170'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=SOTAMAS64", autocommit=True)
cursor = cnxn.cursor() 

cursor.execute("SELECT SalesOrderNo ,UDF_SERIAL_NUMBER FROM SO_SalesOrderHistoryHeader WHERE UDF_SERIAL_NUMBER = ? ORDER BY SalesOrderNo",    serial)
row = cursor.fetchone() 
if row:
    print(row)
```

The DSN is a system dsn setup with the MAS 90 4.0 ODBC Driver (64 bit).
Using Winpython 3.5.